# how to make mockito test case with Constructor injection

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito

I want to make junit test case with mockito

there are Classes.

```
MyProps : the properties data class @Configuration
MyService : my main logic @Service class
MyClient : webClient class @Component
```

how to test myService result logic with mockito?? and how to make data class(MyProps) simply???

there error is like this : 
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Parameter specified as non-null is null:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("application.something")
class MyProps {
    lateinit var broker: String
    lateinit var url: String
}

@Service
class MyService(private val client: MyClient,
                private val myProps: MyProps
){

    fun getReulst(params: Params): Flux<MyEntity> {

        // some logic, and I want check this part result

        return client.get(params)
    }
}

@Component
class MyClient(val myProps: MyProps) {

    private val webClient: WebClient = WebClient.create()

    fun get(params: Params): Flux<MyEntity> {

        val params = BodyInserters.fromValue(query)

        return webClient
                .post()
                .uri(myProps.broker)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(params)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(MyEntity::class.java)
    }
}
```

here is test code

```
//----------------

@SpringBootTest(classes = [MyService::class, MyProps::class, MyClient::class])
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var myProps: MyProps

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var myClient: MyClient

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var countService: MyService


    @BeforeEach
    fun mock() {
        given(myProps.broker).willReturn("http://url.com")
        given(myProps.web).willReturn("something")

        given(myClient.get2(query)).willReturn(
                Flux.fromIterable(listOf(
                        MyEntity("2020-03-22", Count(1)),
                        MyEntity("2020-03-23", Count(2)),
                        MyEntity("2020-03-24", Count(3)),
                        MyEntity("2020-03-25", Count(6)),
                        MyEntity("2020-03-26", Count(5)),
                        MyEntity("2020-03-27", Count(4))
                ))
        )

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun `I want to check!! here`(){
            val param = Params(1,2,3) // some params

            myService.getReulst(param).subscribe() // <-  here is error maybe param is null... why??
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing that looks suspicius is MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) at the end of @BeforeEach

Answer (score 0):

Since you're injecting mocks into your service you don't really need a full-blown spring boot test. This will make your tests faster.

Furthermore, since you're mocking `MyClient`, you're not really calling its code. Therefore whatever happens in `MyClient` can be ignored here. You'll cover it in its own test.

Here's how I'd write this test with JUnit 5 (you'll have to translate it to JUnit 4 if you're still on it):

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class MyServiceTest(
    @Mock val myProps: MyProps,
    @Mock val myClient: MyClient
) {
    // you can use @InjectMocks if you prefer
    val countService: MyService = MyService(myProps, myClient)

    @BeforeEach
    fun mock() {
       // you only need these if they're called in MyService
       `when`(myProps.broker).thenReturn("http://url.com")
       `when`(myProps.web).thenReturn("something")

        `when`(myClient.get(Params(1,2,3))).thenReturn(
            Flux.fromIterable(listOf(
                    MyEntity("2020-03-22", Count(1)),
                    MyEntity("2020-03-23", Count(2)),
                    MyEntity("2020-03-24", Count(3)),
                    MyEntity("2020-03-25", Count(6)),
                    MyEntity("2020-03-26", Count(5)),
                    MyEntity("2020-03-27", Count(4))
            ))
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `I want to check!! here`(){
        val param = Params(1,2,3)

        myService.getReulst(param).subscribe()
    }
}
```